# I don't understand "T::parse.parse(token_stream)" syntax in parse_macro_input macro of syn crate

Tags: rust, macros

```
#[doc(hidden)]
pub fn parse<T: ParseMacroInput>(token_stream: TokenStream) -> Result<T> {
    T::parse.parse(token_stream)
} // Not public API.

#[doc(hidden)]
pub trait ParseMacroInput: Sized {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self>;
}
impl<T: Parse> ParseMacroInput for T {
    fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self> {
        <T as Parse>::parse(input)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format code and take more time to write down your question and what your problems are to understand the code.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that the code you find weird is that in the title:

```
T::parse.parse(token_stream)
```

Here `T` is a generic type that implements `ParseMacroInput`, because of the constraint `T: ParseMacroInput` above. The only member of that trait is that `fn parse(input: ParseStream) -> Result<Self>;` function, so `T::parse` must be a reference to that function.

Now, what about the next `.parse`? Well functions are values too, and they can implement traits. And indeed in `syn`there is this trait:

```
pub trait Parser: Sized {
   // ...
   fn parse(self, tokens: proc_macro::TokenStream) -> Result<Self::Output> { ... }
}
```

and an implementation for functions that take a `ParseStream` and returns a `Result<_>`, just like function `ParseMacroInput::parse`.

```
impl<F, T> Parser for F
where
    F: FnOnce(ParseStream) -> Result<T>
```

And that is the function your original `T::parse.parse()` calls: a function of a trait implemented by a function type or another generic type. The fact that both functions have the same name is an unfortunate coincidence.